# How to read parameters from csv file jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I tried to load csv file in jmeter and read the parameters from the csv file, but i didn't find the solution.

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: And what seems to be the problem exactly? It helps to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

To Read parameters from CSV in JMeter follow this exercise, you will get complete information. [Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Answer (score 0):

1. Given you have `test.csv` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation which looks like:

   ```
   line1
   line2
   line3
   ```
2. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your Test Plan under [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and configure it like:

   [image]
3. That's pretty much it, now you can use `${myVariable}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference where required. Each virtual user on each Thread Group iteration will read the next line from the CSV file into `${myVariable}` and the placeholder will be substituted with the respective value from the CSV file:

   [image]

Check out [JMeter Parameterization - The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) article for more information on above and other approaches to make your JMeter tests [data-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_testing)